# Split Method with single quotes

Tags: c#, parsing

I have a text file with lines of something like this:

> (LIST (LIST 'Abbott 'Ashley 'J ) '8697387888 'ajabbott@mail.usi.edu 2.3073320999676614 )

I have read the file into individual string array elements, but I want to split into individual array elements so it is more useful like:

> |Abbott|Ashley|J|8697387888|ajabott@mail.usi.edu|2.3073320999676614|

However, I can't figure out how to do this. Here is what I have tried, but doesn't work due to syntax.

```
for (int Count = 0; Count < lines.Length; Count++)
{
    Split = lines[Count].Split(''');
}
```

I'm trying to use the single quotes as the split break.

Answer (score 15):

Try using a `\`.

```
 Split = lines[Count].Split('\'');
```

Comment: this isn't the only problem though, given how odd the line he needs to parse is.